# Any possibility to make/create such my lost keystore?

Tags: android, keystore

Unfortunately, my hard disk has been down, and i lost all my data! My keystore included. I published some apps in the market and i want to keep updating them. Is there any possibility to make such old keystore knowing that i know the password of the old one. Please help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

The next time you should use a backup service/system. Email the key yourself might be enough to secure it, too.

Comment: What Warren said. When your keystore is lost, it's really lost. We do not have the means to recover it. Sorry.